# Email address not displaying correct but use bluehost instead

Tags: php, email

I would like to know why does the email as recipient display Bluehost email address instead of my given email inside my PHPMailer.

**Scenario**

I have 3 PHP files.

1. Use to get the info of registrant
2. Use registrant email address
3. Mail Process to confirm registrant and download link

**What Now**

(1)Once a user registered, (2)a simple modal will popup to notify them that he/she will need to confirm the form action. Once done that. (3) An email from our server will process and use his/her email as `Mail TO` while my `Mail From` and `Mail Name` is using my domain info:

1. info@domainname.com (Mail From)
2. Company Name (Mail Name)

**Case Issue**

After several mail test, I am wondering why does the email display as `username@1234.bluehost.com` instead of my given `Mail From`.

Is there any problem with my script or this can be configure via Bluehost? I wanted to know before I proceed and call Bluehost about this.

**Code from PHP**

```
include('class.phpmailer.php');

$post = $_POST;

$recepient = $post['confirmed_mail'];
$carbon    = '';
$bcarbon   = 'bbc@developerEmail.com';

$EmailName = 'Company Name';
$EmailAddress = 'info@companyDomain.com';

$message = 'Message will display here';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsMail();

$mail->FromName = $EmailName; // Sender Name
$mail->From     = $EmailAddress; // Sender Email

$mail->AddAddress($recepient);
$mail->AddCC($carbon);
$mail->AddBCC($bcarbon);

$mail->IsHTML(true); // Send as HTML

$mail->Subject  = "Mail Subject";
$mail->Body     = $message;
$mail->AltBody  = $message;

if (!$mail->Send()) :

  echo "Message was not send, Please check the error <p>";
  echo "Mailer Error: ".$mail->ErrorInfo;

endif;
```

Note: I rename the old code here. `$EmailFrom` to `$EmailName` and `$EmailName` to `$EmailAddress` to avoid confusion.

**Mail Output Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

**PHP Code from Registration**

This is what my pattern where it works fine and receive all information correctly at my Email App.

```
$mail->FromName = ''.$post['rf_fname'].' '.$post['rf_lname'].''; // Sender Name
$mail->From     = $post['rf_email']; // Sender Email
```

Comment: This could depend on how you set the address in your code - which you have not shared - or could be a policy implemented by your host to prevent email abuse. Ask them.

Comment: I have no idea. I've been staring at this for the longest time and can't put my finger on it. I've seen many examples where they're all using the `From` email first, then the person's name. Try inverting the order of these to see if it makes a difference `$mail->FromName = $EmailFrom; // Sender Name
$mail->From     = $EmailName; // Sender Email` - maybe phpmailer is wonky that way. You could also try `$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');`

Comment: I do not have any issue receiving the email after a user register, but the registrant may think that the company email address is spam or bogus once they receive the email download.

Comment: You might start with not adding an empty address as a Cc:.

Comment: Also, while it's not a reason for failure, setting AltBody to the same thing as Body is a very bad idea. Put a text-only representation of the message there. Or, if you really really can't, an "I'm a lazy coder and require you to install an HTML emailer you have no use for otherwise" sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this

```
$EmailFrom = 'Company Name';
$EmailName = 'info@companyDomain.com';

$mail->FromName = $EmailFrom; // Sender Name
$mail->From     = $EmailName; // Sender Email
```

From & Name are the wrong way around, my guess...

Comment: Here's the code that makes me wonder why the email is not working `$mail->FromName = ''.$post['rf_fname'].' '.$post['rf_lname'].''; // Sender Name
$mail->From     = $post['rf_email']; // Sender Email` this is from the Registration form.

Comment: @iMarkDesigns Your can't send email from any domain that you choose to post to your form? Where are you getting there values from? I assume they are a domain that isn't allowed to send email through this server?

Comment: @MattTheNinja 1st of all, I tried your suggestion, but still the result still pointed to mjreals@box1366.bluehost.com, 2nd I do not technically understand your last comment.

Comment: I saw that, and I'm already coordinating it to my client. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this case is fixed and accomplished with the help of Bluehost support.

**Note**

Solutions to this question might be different from the other, though it relates to the other/past questions or problems (which i tried the solution but no luck). Here's why:

1. My PHP Mail script is working correctly and fine.
2. Hosting server do not have email set and up that will reflect as dependent to the SMTP response instead they use GoDaddy email.
3. According to Bluehost: "all we need to do is set up a bogus email account... it doesn't even have to be an account that exists at GoDaddy. As long as the contact form email and the email on the bluehost system match"
4. We create alternative email, "registration@domainname.com"

So after I managed these list, the `Header From: mjreales@box1366.bluehost.com` went to `Header From: MJ Real Estate Investors, Inc. <info@domainname.com>` and it display correctly now.